# Distinction between [wxpython] and [wxpython-phoenix]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

There is currently no indication in the usage guidance as to when which of the two tags should and should not be used, both are

> wxPython is a Python wrapper for the cross-platform C++ GUI API wxWidgets.

I asked this before in the chat, but nobody could conclusively answer the question [so far](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/49309561#49309561). So I tried to find out myself and seemingly [wxpython-phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wxpython-phoenix) is being used for asking issues specific to the latest wxPython release (Version 4) and to porting to it from older versions. Finally I issued the suggestion to change the usage guidance of [wxpython-phoenix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wxpython-phoenix) to

> wxPython Phoenix (alias wxPython 4) is a Python wrapper for the cross-platform C++ GUI API wxWidgets.

.. which is currently pending. In the long term it seems most likely that it will be a synonym to [wxpython](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wxpython).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although my reply in chat was "inconclusive", let me quote my own reasoning:

> [...] it would seem [that wxpython Phoenix refers to the new version of wxpython]. A rewrite of wxpython from scratch, but ultimately just a new version. In my experience we don't keep track of library versions, see e.g. django, pandas, numpy. With this reasoning the tags should be synonyms. But I don't use or know wxpython.

As for proof regarding wxpython's replacement: [the old repo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxPython-Classic) was renamed and archived on github, and [the new Phoenix repo](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix) seems to make it clear that it is *the* wxpython repo that just happens to be a rewrite of the old repo.

Semantically speaking these just seem like different versions of the same library so I suggest making the tags synonyms.

Comment: Does making them synonyms automatically remove the [double tagging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wxpython+wxpython-phoenix)?

Comment: @Wolf yes, they would practically be the same tag.

Comment: I'm not sure if I worded that correctly, I mean: is a question that currently has both tags automatically losing the [wxpython-phoenix] as soon it is made as a synonym to [wxpython] or does it require manual removal?

Comment: @Wolf I believe only the synonym target tag would stay, no manual removal would be necessary.